# How to evaluate an expression with FeynCalc?

Tags: feyncalc

How can I evaluate specific expressions in FeynCalc? For example, if there is a $\delta^i_j$, how can I set $i$ to 1 and $j$ to 2 and make it evaluate to zero?

I've tried

```
TR[GA[µ,v]] /. {µ -> 1, v -> 2}
```

but that does not work, it just yields $4g^{12}$ instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution, albeit not a very pretty one.

One can manually set the elements of the metric tensor via

```
Pair[LorentzIndex[1], LorentzIndex[2]] = 0
```

however one has to do this for every entry.

Comment: Have you tried defining a metric (see e.g. first block of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/230165/18767).